# PHPExcel String to Time

Tags: php, time, phpexcel

I have created an Excel spreadsheet.  In the second column I have values like `0:11:23`  and `2:03:33`, several thousand rows worth.  Using PHP I set the format to be:

```
    $sheet->getStyle($colRange)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_TIME4);
```

But the cells are all still just strings.  If you edit a cell from `0:11:22` to something else like 0:11:33 then the cell WILL get converted into a time.  At the top it goes from `0:11:22` to `0:11:33 AM` this auto addition of AM is what seems to be the huge change, and then I can do what I would like with the file.

How can I change the thousands of cells from `0:11:22` to `0:11:22 AM` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you have to convert the date/time to an MS Excel serialized timestamp, and store that value in the cell; as described in the [PHPExcel Documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#write-a-date-or-time-into-a-cell) and shown in [02types.php](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Examples/02types.php#L99) in the `/Examples` folder.

Once you've stored an actual MS Excel timestamp value, then you can apply a format to it

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A12', 'Date/Time')
    ->setCellValue('B12', 'Time')
        ->setCellValue('C12', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel( $dateTimeNow ));
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('C12')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_TIME4);
```

Comment: Hi Mark, I switched to FORMAT_DATE_TIME8, also you are correct in that it needs to be in timestamp format.  This is about 90% of the way to how they want it.  The only thing now is that if you change 0:01:02 slightly and excel changes it to say 12:01:03 AM - they like that.  But doing it by programming causes it to show "09/20/2016 12:01:03 AM" in the excel formula bar, not just the time like they want...  I understand that you answered the question, but do you have any ideas on how to not show the date part, like as happens when you just change the time manually?

Comment: And, I also fixed my "09/20/2016 12:01:03 AM" issue by removing the date part of the Excel datetime:  12345.6789 -> 0.6789


$val = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getValue();

$timestamp = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $val);

$excelTime = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel($timestamp);

$excelTime = $excelTime - (int)$excelTime;

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($cell, $excelTime);

Answer (score 2):

This is an old post but maybe it would help someone...

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
->setCellValue('E5', '=TEXT(TIMEVALUE("'. $the_str_Time . '"),"[h]:mm")');
```

The TIMEVALUE function turns the string into time,
And the TEXT function gives them a format as desired.
Mine was for measuring time for more then 24 hours

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$sheet
    ->getStyle($colRange)
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode('[$-C09]d mmm yyyy;@');
```

Comment: Hi Denny,  thanks for taking the time - I need it in time, not date format.  I did try using your code with time formats which did format a timestamp correctly, but my problem was not using a timestamp in the first place...