# PHPExcel: How to read time cells with miliseconds like they are displayed in excel

Tags: php, phpexcel

So my sports team (Swimming) asked me to make a small web app to read the times from swimmers and compare it to other swimmers because they knew I'm into programming, although I'm completely new to PHP and I have no clue what I am doing.

Because the sport is swimming the times are pretty precise like: 0:22.13.

The 0 being minutes, 22 seconds and 13ms. I found ways to this if the cells contain Hours Minutes Seconds but not Minutes Seconds Milliseconds...

The code I have right now:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $name = $_POST['user'];
  $uid = -1;

  $inputFileName = "tijden.xls";
  $inputFileType = "Excel5";

  $excel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('tijden.xls');

  $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
  $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
  $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

  $sheet = $excel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null);

  $login = false;

  //echo json_encode($sheet);

  for($i = 1; $i < sizeof($sheet); $i++) {
    if($name == $sheet[$i][1]) {
      $uid = $i;
      $login = true;

      $i = sizeof($sheet);
    }
  }

  if($login) {
    $data = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('K'.$uid)->getCalculatedValue();

    echo($data);
    echo("\n");
  }
}
?>
```

And what it outputs is 0.0014407407407407

So, in short, I want to make PHPExcel read the time cells in a way so the time is displayed properly...

Comment: What is your expected output of that example?

Comment: 0:22.13, sorry I, when I said that time I also meant it as my expected output..  EDIT: Sorry I also made a mistake in the example, the output should be 1:41.57

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:
http://www.osakac.ac.jp/labs/koeda/tmp/phpexcel/Documentation/API/PHPExcel_Style/PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat.html

setFormatCode should have a method to get the exact format that you want.

This might also be relevant: 
[PHPExcel String to Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39565513/phpexcel-string-to-time)